# Geolocation spoofing protection in webapp

Tags: javascript, geolocation, geo, spoofing

I am building a web app which offers users certain unlockable feature at certain locations. And I just realized how easy it is to spoof GPS location. Chrome dev tools even offers GeoLocation custom location override setting under sensors. How can I set effective checks for similar hacks?

**UPDATE:**
Chrome dev tools Geolocation override outputs accuracy of 150m thus IF I set a threshold i.e 40m accuracy (reject all data with accuracy greater than 40m). then that can account for the easy chrome dev tool hack (which is great for testing)

Comment: You can't. Even if you can, you will violate your user privacy.

Comment: sorry , but that seems like a very uninformed answer.  So many location-based apps do have checks against malicious users.  Plus, users agree to share their location.

Comment: @jasan None of those apps actually prevent against malicious users.  I assure, they are all vulnerable.

Comment: JavaScript location, like everything JavaScript, is Client Side, therefore is always subject to user manipulation.

Comment: @jasan Don't forget, we can just bypass your web app and send the appropriate data back to your server.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to prevent users from spoofing their location.  Even if you could prevent it in the client software (and to be clear, you can't), the user could feed a location in via an external GPS (or simply a serial port driver with spoofed location data).

What you *can* do is watch for signs of this spoofing.  You could put in thresholds for location changes and what not.  If someone suddenly appears to move further than is reasonable, you could flag the data as suspicious.  This isn't ideal though, as sometimes immediate location updates happen.  (Suppose your device was in airplane mode before you took off from one city, and then updated as soon as you took it out of airplane mode.  For a short time, the phone thinks it is in one place, and then is immediately transported to the correct place.)

In the end, there's nothing you can reliably do about it, in a generic sense.

Comment: that's a real bummer to hear. I also just found that chrome store has multiple geo-spoofing extensions as well. As you already mentioned I can check for speed(calculated using distance traveled between points and time diff). any other condition that I attach that can increase the chances of detecting spoofing?

Comment: @jasan That depends on the specifics of your application.  What looks like normal to you?  Is this for driving?  Walking?  Related to network traffic?  Only you can determine what's normal for your app.  You might consider testing with real users and looking at the data for outliers.